# WSSCmdlets in Windows 11 home

Tags: powershell

Windows 11 home keeps disabling my Media Streaming Options so my tv can't see my pc.
In Windows Server there is a WSSCmdlets module that seems to be able to enblse streaming options with Set-WssMediaServerEnabled.

This module is not on Windows 11 home though. Is there a way to install the WSSCmdlets module on my Windows 11 home edition? Or is there another way to enable Media Streaming Options via a script?

Comment: See following : https://pureinfotech.com/turn-pc-dlna-media-server-windows-10/